# Format column of floats containing NaN values

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe columns with floats and NaN's and need to format some of them with 0 decimal places and some of them two decimal places. Currently to get the 0 decimal places I am using the code below:

```
    df['myCol'] = df['myCol'].fillna(-1)
    df['myCol'] = df['myCol'].astype(int)
    df['myCol'] = df['myCol'].astype(str)
    df['myCol'] = df['myCol'].replace('-1', '')
```

Is there a faster way to do this and what is the best way for formatting the columns where two decimal places are necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `df.round()`

```
df['myCol'] = df['myCol'].round(decimals=2)
```

Comment: I am printing the dataframe into an html template, so my question didnt really make sense.